# IsAuthorized of the AuthorizeAttribute is always false in the unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to test my custom `AuthorizeAttribute`, but the `IsAuthorized` method of the base class always returns false regardless of `IsAuthenticated`. Let me show you some code (some parts are omitted for brevity):

**AuthorizeAttribute**

```cs
public class UserAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!base.IsAuthorized(actionContext)) // always returns false
            return false;

        //... not important user permission check

        return true;
    }
}
```

**GetPrincipal** method mocks `IPrincipal`

```cs
public static IPrincipal GetPrincipal()
{
    var user = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
    var identity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
    identity.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("Superman");
    identity.Setup(p => p.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
    user.Setup(x => x.Identity).Returns(identity.Object);
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = user.Object;

    return user.Object;
}
```

**TestMethod**

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    HttpActionContext actionContext = ContextUtil.CreateActionContext();

    var attribute = new UserAuthorizeAttribute();
    IPrincipal user = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

    // yep, this passes
    Assert.IsTrue(user.Identity.IsAuthenticated, "Superman is not authenticated");

    attribute.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
}
```

According to the [source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) of the attribute it should only check the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` as I'm not assigning any users or roles specifically. Any clue what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principal is not taken from the current thread, but from the `actionContext`. So, what you must set is the principal in the request context of the action context:

```
actionContext.RequestContext.Principal = yourPrincipal;
```

Do this right after creating the action context, and before invoking the tested method.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. However I had to change it to `actionContext.RequestContext.Principal`. Question: do I have a link to the old version of the source code or something?

Comment: Nope! I read it directly from your link. Look for this code: `IPrincipal user = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal;`

Comment: @Zabavsky, facing similar issue. I'm not writting code in unit test. The Principal is returned from Azure AD and when `base.IsAuthorized(actionContext)` is executed, it is always returned `false`